# Dealing with Services, creating the Service thread from within the main class or in the service class itself?

Tags: android

Talking theoretically, before having started with my application, is it better to create the new thread from within the MyMain class (The one which extends `Activity`) or do we usually create it in the MyService class ( The one which extends `Service` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you need to work with the UI, start a thread from the activity. If you need to work in the background, do it in a Service. And generally you shouldn't need to use 'raw' threads -- use `AsyncTask` for activities and `IntentService` for services.